# Wpf datagrid scrolling with rowdetails

Tags: wpf, scroll, wpfdatagrid, virtualization, rowdetails

we have a datagrid with around 360 rowos and each row cntains another datagrid with approximately 30 rows. We need the virtualization to be turned on but then we have an issue with scrolling. Once the master row is not visible, expanded rowdetails dissapear too. We are using .net 4.0

Comment: Can you share some code to make this question clear?